# how to view all files in linux using grep?

Tags: linux

I'm trying to view the files in the linux (xubuntu) terminal (like this command: `ls`).
Is there a way to do it with the command `grep`? Thanks for helpers.

Comment: `grep` looks into files and will list them if the expression you give matches what is in the file. Let's say you have 50 files in a directory that contain `"yoga"` and you have to find those files. Then `grep 'yoga' *` would search all files for the word `"yoga"` returning the matches to you. Using the `-H` option will return a list of files that match similar to `ls`.

Comment: Is there any reason you want to use grep and not ls? Both are different tools for different reasons and purposes.

Comment: This seems more like an https://xyproblem.info/ to me. What's wrong with using `ls`? And, if that's not suitable for your purposes, than surely the `find` command would be. The `grep` command is meant for *finding* data *within* files, not for listing filenames (though it is possible to do so).

Comment: @costaparas I know that `ls` is better but I got H.W and one of the exercises was to do it with `grep`...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use recursive  (`-r`) and only filename (`-l`)

```
grep -r . -l
```

You can set a directory action (`-d skip`) to only grep files in a directory

```
grep -r . -d skip -l *
```

Comment: Fun fact: it will omit empty files and files with only empty lines.

Comment: @KamilCuk Good to know but I assume/hope that OP doesn't want to just replace `ls` with `grep`. I think OP wants to recursively search for something in a directory.

Comment: @ThomasSablik it shows me the whole files in this folder, and all of the files in the sub-folders, is there a way for using it just as regular `ls` command (no parameters)?

Comment: !!! You can always set alias grep='ls -a' in you .bashrc!! Of course then you can not use grep!